# My first xcode view controller does not act like the others. Why?

Tags: ios, xcode, view, controller

Right now I have [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfELn.png).
It shows me being able to drag the button into viewcontroller.swift Using the root View Controller.

Next please take a look at [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGnV2.png).
This picture shows me not being able to drag the button into viewcontroller.swift using my 3rd View Controller.

May someone please help me? I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

For every view controller in storyboard you need to associate it with a view controller class. and component of one view controller in drag-able only its associated view controller  class. what I understand you are trying to drag component of one view controller to not associated class.

Select Automatic option on when active assistant coding page.