# post image with Caption in Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, camera

I successfully post image as well as video but i can't post the caption with image
this my code

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath());

                SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                        .setBitmap(bitmap)
                        .setCaption(" do that thing you don't like!")
                        .build();

                SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                        .addPhoto(photo)
                        .build();


                shareButton.setShareContent(content);
```

how can possible to add caption with image.thanks in advance for help me. i refer developer.facebook.com site

Comment: I Would Help You If I Could But could you help me? :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31130305/my-first-xcode-view-controller-does-not-act-like-the-others-why

Comment: This looks like a potential bug. Can you report it here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs